# Why did not they make a distribution for Ubuntu Server 13.04 for 32-bit?

Tags: server

What happened to the 32-bit version of Ubuntu?

I understand that the current 64-bit PCs are coming, but there are places in the world where 32-bit is still used.

Answer (score 0):

The i386 builds of Ubuntu haven't gone anywhere. You can download the ISO at [releases.ubuntu.com](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/) for i386, amd64, or even for armhf+omap4 on the server.